# Having problem opening windows .doc file

Tags: windows, libreoffice, microsoft-office

I am getting bordered boxes and tables which makes file look awkward in libreoffice when I open the .doc extension file which have no such thing in Microsoft Office in Windows.

Comment: .doc files are not portable. You could maybe try saving the file as .odt in MS Office, but Office (and MS in general) often plays by its own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution will be use a portable file version, like `.odt`, but I'm assuming you really want to use `.doc` files.

## Solution 1: Update your LibreOffice

As LibreOffice is always improving MSOffice compatibility, you can install the latest stable LibreOffice version, using their fresh PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Accept then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

## Solution 2: Install MSOffice

**Disclaimer**: I'm supposing you have the MSOffice installer and a valid license. Additionally, keep in your mind MSOffice has no Linux support.

Using PlayOnLinux, which is a wizard to install and configure Windows software running on Linux using Wine, you can install some MSOffice versions, like 2010 (which runs smoothly).

First, install PlayOnLinux and some other required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux samba winbind
```

Then follow [this tutorial steps](https://gist.github.com/raelgc/4ccc023830bfd12c0227).

Comment: Solution 3: Use WPS Office for Linux: http://wps-community.org/

Comment: WPS Office is good but is there open source alternative of it

Comment: @jkp Of course, the one mentioned in Solution 1 above. Open source and installed by default. And you can have both. WPS is proprietary but also free, unlike the one mentioned in Solution 2, for which a license is required and the installation with Wine in Ubuntu is not supported.

Comment: @jkp I prefer, of course, the open source solution. LibreOffice is installed by default but not using the latest version,  so the solution 1 is use the latest stable available. Solution 2 you said is "not supported", but PlayOnLinux has a ready-to-use script to install MSOffice 2010. So, of course, it's not supported by MS, but it's supported by Wine/PlayOnLinux/Crossover. Anyway, I'll update Solution 2 to mention the need of a license.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have latest version of LibreOffice with me still is not working so Solution 1 even fails.